# Tratando de obtener una propiedad non-object en Yii2 (Trying to get property of non-object en yii2)

Tags: php, yii2

Hay varias consultas con este mismo titulo, pero la verdad que lo que me pasa es muy raro, ya que en localhost me aparece y en linea no aparece este mensaje y funciona bien, por eso me atreví a consultar sobre un tema que ya estaba.

este es el código que produce ese ewrror.
codigo en localhost: index.php

```
[
  'attribute' => 'users_id',
  'value' => function($model) {
      $usuario = Users::findOne($model
      ->users_id);
      return $usuario->nombre; //en eta linea marca el error
   },
   'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(Users::find()
    ->where('rol_id = 1')->all(),'id','nombre'),
],
```

Y este es código online:

```
[
  'attribute' => 'users_id',
  'value' => function($model) {
   $usuario = Users::findOne($model->users_id);
   return $usuario->nombre;
   },
   'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Users::find()->where('rol_id = 1')->all(), 'id', 'nombre'),
],
```

Como se puede ver es exactamente igual. y en el index que lo ponga me da el mismo error.

Por favor me pueden ayudar.

Comment: Puede que en remoto no hayas incluido correctamente la clase `Users` o la clase `ArrayHelper` u otra cosa y por eso te de el error.  De todos modos, puedes guardar una variable y hacer un `var_dump($variable);` para ver el estado del objeto.

Comment: Puede que no tengas bien la bd de datos que usas en remoto

Comment: Gracias: Comparé las 2 online y localhost y estan iguales. Ahora en linea me da este error: Method Not Allowed (#405) Método no permitido. Esta URL solo puede manejar los siguientes métodos de solicitud: POST.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, revisando la tabla, me encontré que se había corrompido, exporte una que tenia online y se soluciono, esto ocurrió despues de haber hecho un cambio en la tabla. Gracias